# Can someone explain me about these lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
set_9 = {1,2,3,4,5}
for a in set_9:
    print(f"{a:>6.2f}")
```

Output

```
  1.00
  2.00
  3.00
  4.00
  5.00
```

1. Is `:>` an operator? If not, what type is it?
2. What is `6.2f` mean?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Answer (score 0):

The format used is called [Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) or f-strings, which is `f"{a:>6.2f}"`

Anything inside the curly braces is replacement field, which is `{a:>6.2f}`

Here, `a` is the field_name and `>6.2f` is the format_spec.

> replacement_field ::=  "{" [field_name] ["!" conversion] [":"
> format_spec] "}"

Expanding the [format specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) used in your example:

- > - align - Right align the field
- 6 - width - Minimum width (by default space is used as
  fill character)
- .2 - precision - Number of digits after the decimal point
- f - type - Floating point notation

Comment: @MaxTan Its just the separator between field_name and format_spec

"{" [field_name] ["!" conversion] ["**:**" format_spec] "}"